# CSS selector for current row in GMail

Tags: jquery, gmail, css-selectors

I'm trying to get to the row that is "current" in GMail Inbox view, the one marked by a little triangle on the left. The one you can change using j,k hotkeys.
I came up with this but it still returns every row.

```
jQuery("#canvas_frame").contents().find('tr#.zA>td:first-child>img[style]')
```

I need two selectors - one for the current row and another for every other row, not including the current.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see a triangle nor am I able to change anything using my j & k keys.

Comment: what happens when you hit "x"? Do you get a row selected? If yes, then look immediately to the left of the checkbox. If not, I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Actually, I have an idea. Check your Settings>General>Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have the keyboard shortcuts enabled. Also, I had a theme selected where you can't see the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I messed around with it, you can select the current row with

```
var selectedRow = jQuery("#canvas_frame").contents()
 .find('tr').removeClass('sel').end()
 .find('.oZ-jd[style*=visibility]').closest('tr').addClass('sel');

var nonSelectedRows = selectedRow.closest('table').find('tr').not('.sel');
```

Comment: That works, thanks. What's the etiquette, should I accept your answer and post another question as follows?

I can't make it work inside keyup:
$().keyup(listenJK);
function listenJK(event){
  var key = {j: 74, k: 75 };
  switch (event.keyCode){
    case key.j: case key.k:
      var current_row = jQuery("#canvas_frame").contents().find('tr').removeClass('sel').end().find('.oZ-jd[style*=visibility]').closest('tr').addClass('sel');
      alert(jQuery("#canvas_frame").contents().length);
  }
}

I'm getting "0" in the alert.

Comment: It might be best to ask a separate question, because if I am unable to answer the next question, it's rare that older questions are even looked at... but, in your code, it looks like `$()` should be `$('#canvas_frame').contents()` or maybe try binding a live event to the keyup inside the iframe. I'll try it later when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks, fudgey. I'm very new to this, can't make any sense out of "try binding a live event to the keyup inside the iframe".